# Transfer leads information to custom modules while converting leads in zoho crm

Tags: zoho

Please tell me how can we transfer leads information to custom modules while converting leads to contacts, potentials, accounts in zoho crm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with a workflow rule & custom function.  Here's an overview of what you want to do:

1. Convert Lead
2. Lead data is transferred into either Account, Contact, or Potential record.  Let's use the Contact record for this example.  (This means all Lead data that you need to use in your Custom Module record must also be contained in the Contact record)
3. Set up workflow rule so that when new Contact record is created, it calls a Custom Function.
4. Custom function uses zoho.crm.create() function to create new record in your custom module.